# fullpage.js resizing dots to ease browsing through mobiles

Tags: javascript, css, fullpage.js

I'm using Fullpage.js to do my website.. I want to resize the dots that change pages, to bigger ones and change their colors to white.. any advice ?

Answer (score 1):

Yep. Override the following CSS styles applied by fullPage.js to them:

- #fp-nav (`ul`, `li`, `li:hover a.active span`, `a`, `a.active span`, `a span`)

And the same for `.fp-slidesNav`.

You can find their whole default styles [here](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/blob/master/jquery.fullPage.css).